# Python - Remove tab and new line in Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Just a new user of scrapy.org and a newbie to Python. I have this values at **brand** and **title** properties (**JAVA OOP Term**) that contains tab spaces and new line. How can we trim it to make this 2 following object properties to have this plain string value

```
item['brand'] = "KORAL ACTIVEWEAR"
item['title'] = "Boom Leggings"
```

Below is the data structure

```
{'store_id': 870, 'sale_price_low': [], 'brand': [u'\n                KORAL ACTIVEWEAR\n              '], 'currency': 'AUD', 'retail_price': [u'$140.00'], 'category': [u'Activewear'], 'title': [u'\n                Boom Leggings\n              '], 'url': [u'/boom-leggings-koral-activewear/vp/v=1/1524019474.htm?folderID=13331&fm=other-shopbysize-viewall&os=false&colorId=68136'], 'sale_price_high': [], 'image_url': [u'  https://images-na.sample-store.com/images/G/01/samplestore/p/prod/products/kacti/kacti3025868136/kacti3025868136_q1_2-0._SH20_QL90_UY365_.jpg\n'], 'category_link': 'https://www.samplestore.com/clothing-activewear/br/v=1/13331.htm?baseIndex=500', 'store': 'SampleStore'}
```

I was able to trim the prices to only get the number and decimal by using regex search method, which I think might be wrong when there is a price comma separator.

```
price = re.compile('[0-9\.]+')
item['retail_price'] = filter(price.search, item['retail_price'])
```

Comment: It looks like leading and trailing white space only - something like `x.strip()` should be good enough. Why regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do, at least for this example, is strip all whitespace off the edges of the `brand` and `title` values. You don't need a regex for that, just call the `strip` method.

However, your `brand` isn't a single string; it's a list of strings (even if there's only one string in the list). So, if you try to just `strip` it, or run a regex on it, you're going to get an `AttributeError` or `TypeError` from trying to treat that list as a string.

To fix this, you need to map the `strip` over all of the strings, with either the `map` function or a list comprehension:

```
item['brand'] = [brand.strip() for brand in item['brand']]
item['title'] = map(str.strip, item['title'])
```

… whichever of the two is easier for you to understand.

---

If you have other examples that have embedded runs of whitespace, and you want to turn every such run into exactly one space character, you need to use the `sub` method with your regex:

```
item['brand'] = [re.sub(ur'\s+', u' ', brand.strip() for brand in item['brand']]
```

Notice the `u` prefixes. In Python 2, you need a `u` prefix to make a `unicode` literal instead of a `str` (encoded bytes) literal. And it's important to use Unicode patterns against Unicode strings, even if the pattern itself doesn't care about any non-ASCII characters. (If all of this seems like a pointless pain and a bug magnet—well, it is; that's the main reason Python 3 exists.)

---

As for the `retail_price`, the same basic observations apply. Again, it's a list of strings, not just a string. And again, you probably don't need regex. Assuming the price is always a `$` (or other single-character currency marker) followed by a number, just slice off the `$` and call `float` or `Decimal` on it:

```
item['retail_price'] = [float(price[1:]) for price in item['retail_price']]
```

… but if you have examples that look different, with arbitrary extra characters on both sides of the price, you can use `re.search` here, but you'll still need to map it, and to use a Unicode pattern.

You also need to grab the matching `group` out of the search, and to handle empty/invalid strings in some way (they'll return `None` for the search, and you can't convert that to a `float`). You have to decide what to do about it, but from your attempt with `filter` it looks like you just want to skip them. This is complicated enough that I'd do it in multiple steps:

```
prices = item['price']
matches = (re.search(r'[0-9.]+', price) for price in prices)
groups = (match.group() for match in matches if match)
item['price'] = map(float, validmatches)
```

… or maybe wrap that in a function.

Comment: Got an error: item['brand'] = item['brand'].strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Take note that item['brand'] has this value [u'\n                KORAL ACTIVEWEAR\n              ']. I don't know what is "u" after the opening bracket [

Comment: @user1441797 The answer explains why you get that `AttributeError`, and what to do about it, and also explains the `u` prefix. I've edited it to explain even further.

Comment: I like the way you explain the whole thing. Solves my questions. Upvoted! Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the retailer_price stuff. I do encounter different currency prefixes. It depends on the site on how they display their prices with currency abbreviations and symbols. E.g. A$12.99, USD 12.99, $12.99

Comment: item['retail_price'] = [float(re.search(ur'[0-9.]+', price)) for price in item['retail_price']] resulted to 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: @user1441797 OK, you need two things there. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: This is actually better! Kudos @abarnert

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method like below which takes an object and returns all the leaves normalized.

```
import six

def normalize(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, six.string_types):
        return ' '.join(obj.split())
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [normalize(x) for x in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k:normalize(v) for k,v in obj.items()}
    return obj
```

This is a recursive method and does not modify the original object instead returns the normalized object. You can also use it for normalizing the strings.

For your example item

```
>> item = {'store_id': 870, 'sale_price_low': [], 'brand': [u'\n                KORAL ACTIVEWEAR\n              '], 'currency': 'AUD', 'retail_price': [u'$140.00'], 'category': [u'Activewear'], 'title': [u'\n                Boom Leggings\n              '], 'url': [u'/boom-leggings-koral-activewear/vp/v=1/1524019474.htm?folderID=13331&fm=other-shopbysize-viewall&os=false&colorId=68136'], 'sale_price_high': [], 'image_url': [u'  https://images-na.sample-store.com/images/G/01/samplestore/p/prod/products/kacti/kacti3025868136/kacti3025868136_q1_2-0._SH20_QL90_UY365_.jpg\n'], 'category_link': 'https://www.samplestore.com/clothing-activewear/br/v=1/13331.htm?baseIndex=500', 'store': 'SampleStore'}

>> print (normalize(item))
>> {'category': [u'Activewear'], 'store_id': 870, 'sale_price_low': [], 'title': [u'Boom Leggings'], 'url': [u'/boom-leggings-koral-activewear/vp/v=1/1524019474.htm?folderID=13331&fm=other-shopbysize-viewall&os=false&colorId=68136'], 'brand': [u'KORAL ACTIVEWEAR'], 'currency': 'AUD', 'image_url': [u'https://images-na.sample-store.com/images/G/01/samplestore/p/prod/products/kacti/kacti3025868136/kacti3025868136_q1_2-0._SH20_QL90_UY365_.jpg'], 'category_link': 'https://www.samplestore.com/clothing-activewear/br/v=1/13331.htm?baseIndex=500', 'sale_price_high': [], 'retail_price': [u'$140.00'], 'store': 'SampleStore'}
```